# WPF DrawingContext too slow

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, rendering

I've written an audio visualization using WPF and a DrawingContext + DrawingVisual.
The problem is that it is quite slow. So I've startet my profiler and this is the result:
http://s14.directupload.net/images/130414/rnizoyw2.png

I can't see any lines to improve performance. So you may have any ideas how to improve performance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of drawing to a new DrawingVisual and then rendering that Visual into a RenderTargetBitmap, you could directly write to a [WriteableBitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.writeablebitmap%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Use that WriteableBitmap as the Source of your Image control.

From the Remarks section in WriteableBitmap:

> Use the WriteableBitmap class to update and render a bitmap on a
>   per-frame basis. This is useful for generating algorithmic content,
>   such as a fractal image, and for data visualization, such as a music
>   visualizer.

You may also want to take a look at the [WriteableBitmapEx](https://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/) library.

Comment: hmmm as far as I can see... I can just use Colors to set pixel by pixel. What happens if I want a to use gradientbrush or anything like that?